# Can't find App.cs in Xamarin PCL project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I do as tutorial here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679501.aspx

and when I try to change default page in App.cs.

I can't find this **App.cs** file in PCL project.

What I do wrong or how can I create App.cs file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in xamarin.android remove the reference of xamarin.forms project and add it again. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of the Forms project templates will name the default startup class file "MyProject.cs" (ie, whatever you named your project when you created it) instead of App.cs.

Comment: There is also no file like that in project. and I try to create App.cs file myself but it look like this class is never called.

Comment: It is called from your platform project's initialization - either AppDelegate.cs for iOS or MainActivity.cs on Android

Comment: I check on my MainActivity.cs. It's just set content view to some layout and set a button event in OnCreate.
Is it possible that my droid project does not link to PCL project?
and it also have a warning symbol on PCL Project in "References" of Droid project.

Comment: It sounds like you created a Xamarin Android project instead of a Xamarin Forms project

Comment: Wow it's my stupidity.I just found out that I create "Native Portable" instead of "Xamarin.Forms".
Thanks for you help.